# WPF - Generar combobox mediante un List<object> en VS propertyGrid

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net, wpf, combobox

Dispongo de una propiedad de tipo "List" en el propertyGrid, donde el usuario inserta las zonas que estime:

[image: ListaZonas]

Necesito crear, también en el propertyGrid, un combo que cargue automáticamente las zonas que el usuario ha insertado en la lista.

Dicho combo recargará automáticamente las zonas si el usuario mete nuevas en la lista.

Dispongo de un ejemplo con una lista generada a mano que me crea el combo correctamente:

[image: Combo con lista generada por código]

El problema viene cuando asocio el listado de zonas en vez del generado por código.

El resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:

[image: Resultado erróneo]

El código que dispongo es el siguiente:

**Zona.cs**

```
    public class Zona
    {
        private string m_nombre;
        private int m_id;

        public Zona() { }

        public Zona(string n, int i)
        {
            m_nombre = n;
            m_id = i;
        }

        public string Nombre
        {
            get => m_nombre;
            set => m_nombre = value;
        }

        public int Id
        {
            get => m_id;
            set => m_id = value;
        }

        public string Descripcion { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0},{1}", m_nombre, m_id);
        }

        public static Zona Parse(string zonaString)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(zonaString))
            {
                return new Zona();
            }

            // The parts array holds the real and 
            // imaginary parts of the object.
            var parts = zonaString.Split(',');
            return new Zona((parts[0].Trim()), int.Parse(parts[1].Trim()));
        }
    }

    public class ZonaTypeConverter : TypeConverter
    {
        public static List<Zona> defaultValues = new List<Zona>();


        static ZonaTypeConverter()
        {
            // Estos son los datos que se mostrarán en el combo
            defaultValues.Add(new Zona("Opcion1", 0));
            defaultValues.Add(new Zona("Opcion2", 1));
            defaultValues.Add(new Zona("Opcion3", 2));
            defaultValues.Add(new Zona("Opcion4", 3));
            defaultValues.Add(new Zona("Opcion5", 4));
            defaultValues.Add(new Zona("Opcion6", 5));
        }

        // Override CanConvertFrom to return true for String-to-Complex conversions.
        public override bool CanConvertFrom(
            ITypeDescriptorContext context,
            Type sourceType)
        {
            if (sourceType == typeof(string))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
        }

        // Override CanConvertTo to return true for Complex-to-String conversions.
        public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
        {
            if (destinationType == typeof(string))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
        }

        // Override ConvertFrom to convert from a string to an instance of Complex.
        public override object ConvertFrom(
            ITypeDescriptorContext context,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture,
            object value)
        {
            var text = value as string;

            if (text != null)
            {   
                return Zona.Parse(text);
            }
            return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
        }

        // Override ConvertTo to convert from an instance of Complex to string.
        public override object ConvertTo(
            ITypeDescriptorContext context,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture,
            object value,
            Type destinationType)
        {
            if (destinationType == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("destinationType");
            }

            //Convert Complex to a string in a standard format.
            var c = value as Complex;

            if (c != null && CanConvertTo(context, destinationType))
            {
                return c.ToString();
            }
            return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
        }

        public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override TypeConverter.StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(
            ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            ComplexNumberControl num = (ComplexNumberControl)context.Container;
            // defaultValues = num.ListaZonas;

            var svc = new StandardValuesCollection(null);

            if (num is null)
            {
                svc = new StandardValuesCollection(defaultValues);
            }
            else
            {
                svc = new StandardValuesCollection(num.ListaZonas);
            }

            //defaultValues.Add(new Zona("prueba", 10));
            //defaultValues.Add(new Zona("Op4564531233cion1", 0));

            return svc;
        }
    }
```

Y en el **xaml.cs**

```
public partial class ComplexNumberControl : UserControl
    {
        public ComplexNumberControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Complex ComplexNumber
        {
            get => (Complex)GetValue(ComplexNumberProperty);

            set => SetValue(ComplexNumberProperty, value);
        }

        public Zona ZonaSeleccionada
        {
            get => (Zona)GetValue(ZonaSeleccionadaProperty);

            set => SetValue(ZonaSeleccionadaProperty, value);
        }

        public List<Zona> ListaZonas
        {
            get
            {
               return (List<Zona>)GetValue(ListaZonasProperty);
            }
            set => SetValue(ListaZonasProperty, value);
        }


        private List<Zona> _ListZonas = new List<Zona>();

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ComplexNumberProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
          "ComplexNumber",
          typeof(Complex),
          typeof(ComplexNumberControl),
          new PropertyMetadata(new Complex()));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ZonaSeleccionadaProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
         "ZonaSeleccionada",
         typeof(Zona),
         typeof(ComplexNumberControl),
         new PropertyMetadata(new Zona()));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ListaZonasProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
       "ListaZonas",
       typeof(List<Zona>),
       typeof(ComplexNumberControl),
       new PropertyMetadata(new List<Zona>()));
    }
```

Como se puede observar, las propiedades se encuentran en un Control de **WPF** que en este ejemplo he añadido a "MainWindow".

**Otro problema que tengo es que no me permite depurar en tiempo de diseño.**

Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda.